# Create Fish alias for 'git add remote...'

Tags: git, heroku, alias, fish

I usually forget how to push from two different Macs to the same heroku app, so I always end looking in google til I find the command  `git add remote heroku git@heroku.com:my_project.git`.

I want to create an alias for this command, in which I just need to use the alias and the name of the app as an argument, something like this: `herokuadd thenameofmyapp`.

I tried to create it using alias herokuadd `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:$argv.git` but it doesn't work and can't figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `alias`, Fish just appends your ARGV to the end of the command. Try aliasing something to `echo` to see:

```
alias herokuadd "echo git@heroku.com:$argv.git"
herokuadd foo
# git@heroku.com:.git foo
```

If you write a `function` instead, you can inline `$argv[1]`:

```
function herokuadd
  echo git@heroku.com:$argv[1].git
end
herokuadd foo
# git@heroku.com:foo.git
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working!! I just needed to remove the [1] part.

Comment: Really? Since you only have one argument anyway, `$argv` and `$argv[1]` should behave the same in this case (and appear to in my tests).

Comment: I know, but somehow it echoes something like 'theres no git repository' or something like it, I can't recall it exactly.

Answer (score 3):

```
git config --global alias.herokuadd '!herokuadd() { git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:$1.git; }; herokuadd'
```

should be what you are after.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't know Fish, now I understand. :-) But why don't you just use a git alias like I suggested, or does this not work in your setup?

Answer (score 1):

Git aliases can get parameters from the command line

Here is a sample im using:

```
[alias]
    ra = "!f() { git remote add $1 https://bitbucket.org/$2.git; }; f"
```

You can always add more command separated with the `;` or with `&&` to execute several command if you wish to add remote and pull on the same time.

Another option is to use script with the git alias.
Here is an example on how to execute script:

```
[alias]
    l = "!bash -c 'source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log'"
```

In your case since you are using fish you can set the ur hardcoded (to be the same on all your machines) and simply use git alias without any parameters.

```
[alias]
    set_remote = "git remote add <name> <url>"
```